# How to redirect stdout and stderr to the same file

Tags: grep, stdout, stderr

How to redirect both standard output and standard error to the same file?
so if there is a command like `grep "ABC" /etc/passwd > output` 
this only directs the standard output to this file
whereas `grep "ABC" /etc/passwd 2> output` redirects the standard error to output file
Is there a command that can take care of both stdout and stderr and direct it to the same file

Answer (score 0):

To redirect both std error and std output, you can try any of these;

```
$ grep "ABC" /etc/passwd &> output
$ grep "ABC" /etc/passwd >& output 
$ grep "ABC" /etc/passwd > output 2>&1
```